# Whether the image is a subspace of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$V$ and $ W $are two real vector spaces.

$T: V \rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation.

What is the image of $T$ and how can I prove that it is a subspace of W?

Comment: I think this might be a possible dubplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017649/kernel-and-image-subspaces-proof

Comment: $ImT = \{w \in W | \exists v \in V$ s.t $ T(v) = w\}$

As to how to prove this is a subset of $W$, you can see the linked question above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kernel and image subspaces proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017649/kernel-and-image-subspaces-proof)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image of the linear transform $T: V \to W$ is simply the set of all points in $W$ that are "reached" / affected by $T$.

More formally,
$$
Im(T) = \{ T(v)\ | \ v \in V\} 
$$

For example, consider the linear transform 
$$
T: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R \\
T(x) = x + 1
$$
The image of $T$ will be $[1, 2]$ even though the codomain in $\mathbb R$, since all of $\mathbb R$ is not reached by $T$ acting on $[0, 1]$.

The image of $T$  is clearly a subset of $W$, so all you need to do is to show that it is a subspace. To do this, you need to show that the linear combination of any two elements in $W$ is still an element in $W$.

Let $w_1, w_2 \in Im (T)$ and let $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb R$. Consider 
$$
r_1w_1 + r_2w_2
$$

Since $w_1, w_2 \in Im(T)$, that means that there exists $v_1, v_2 \in V$ such that $w_1 = T(v_1)$ and $w_2 = T(v_2)$. Hence, rewrite the original expression as

$$
r_1 T(v_1) + r_2 T(v_2) = \\
T(r_1v_1) + T(r_2v_2) = \\
T(r_1v_1 + r_2v_2)
$$

But $T(r_1v_1 + r_2v_2) \in Im(T)$, and hence the linear combination of $w_1$ and $w_2$ is in $Im(T)$. Hence, $Im(T)$ is a subspace of $W$.

Comment: This proof is correct, but the first map T isn't a linear transformation (note T(2x) =/= 2*T(x), and indeed the image of T, {1,2}, is not a subspace since it does not contain 0).